# Multiple grouping variables using kableExtra

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I've got the following dataset:

```
tab <- tibble(year = c(2017,2017,2017,2018,2018,2018) 
              mth  = c("Apr", "Apr", "Jun", "Jul", "Jul", "Sep"),
              var1 = 1:6,
              var2 = 10:15)
```

Is it possible to use kableExtra to generate a table of this data where there are two grouping variables, `year` and `month`? This would give:

```
        var1 var2
2017
    Apr   
          1   10
          2   11
    Jun   
          3   12
2018
    Jul
          4   13
          5   14
    Sep   
          6   15
```

I've tried:

```
kable(tab[,3:4]) %>% pack_rows(index = table(year$Month, tab$mth))
```

It works fine with one grouping variable, but it doesn't work for two grouping variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html) tutorial has great examples and explains how to do this.

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

kable(tab, align = "c", col.names = c("","",names(tab)[3:4])) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = T) %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1:2, valign = "top")
```

Comment: That's great. When I apply this to my own data I get `Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent` . Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: Ok. I worked it out - I wasn't selecting the correct column range in the first line.